# I have a dataset of 3 dimensions. Two of them are of categorical type. How do I plot them in 3dplot?

Tags: r, plot

To illustrate:

```
x=rep(c(rep(1,4),rep(3,4),rep(6,4)),4)
y=rep(c(1,10,100,1000),12)
z=runif(48)
mydata=cbind(x,y,z)
scatterplot3d(mydata,pch=16,xlab="months",
ylab="parameter",zlab="values")
```

Here, *x* is number of months of which I have only three categories and *y* are values of four parameters used in my study. I want my x axis to show only 1,3,6 and the y axis to show only 1,10,100,1000 with equidistant separation on the axis. The present plot plots y axis as 0,200,400,600,800,1000. So my three data points pertaining to 1,10 and 100 values of *y* are restricted to a narrow zone.

Comment: Why do you want a 3d scatterplot? Scatter plots are designed to have a continuous axis in all dimensions. You might consider using a faceted display of histograms (with the facets being the categorical axes) instead.

Comment: @WHoekstra Wonderful advice. That works.

Answer (score 0):

set(gca,'yscale','log')

A log scale on the y-axis should give you what you're looking for in this instance. More generally, if you want axis points equidistant regardless of their value you might consider storing their values as a string and see what that does for you.

Comment: Is there any direct way to play with the values of a particular axis. For example, if I had four categorical values in y variable like low, medium, high, very high. How should I do that? I tried setting the variable as factors but that is not working somehow.